# How to make Shutdown button with CSS3?

Tags: button, css

I am trying to make shutdown button using CSS3 similar to this picture 
http://static.desktopnexus.com/thumbnails/25080-bigthumbnail.jpg
So far I got [this](http://jsbin.com/afineg/6/edit). The issues are that I cannot make that "semi-circle" look like that circle in the center of image, cannot center that "semi-circle" and box-shadow ruins that "semi-circle".
Do you have any suggestions to improve what I am trying to do?
Thnx in advance!

Comment: If this isn't for some kind of contest or the like, consider just using an image :)

Comment: I am just curious if it's possible to do something like this using CSS3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my attempt:

```css
.shutdown {
    border: 8px solid #0cf;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0cf, inset 0 0 10px #0cf;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}

.shutdown .inner {
    border: 5px solid #0cf;
    border-radius: 100px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0cf, inset 0 0 10px #0cf;
    height: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}

.shutdown .bar {
    border-left: 5px solid #0cf;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #0cf;
    height: 20px;
    left: 47px;
    position: relative;
    top: -15px;
    width: 0;
}

.shutdown .sub-bar {
    border-left: 11px solid black;
    height: 30px;
    margin-left: 44px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
}​
```

Here's the HTML structure to go along with it:

```
<div class="shutdown">
    <div class="inner"></div>
    <div class="sub-bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
</div>​
```

And [here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/zAKMH/).